# How to run a batch file from a tcl-file inside Quartus?

Tags: batch-file, tcl, quartus

I would like to run from Quartus a tcl-File which runs a batch file while the batch file reads a user input.

The first problem is that I do not see the cmd-line where I can see the user input at all.

The tcl-file runs the .bat file like this:

```
exec cmd \/c D:/test/run.bat
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're not running this from a non-console-mode application. If you were, a console would be popping up automatically. There's many questions about this and how to prevent it, but you appear to have the inverse question.

By default, Tcl runs subprocesses so that they're connected back to the Tcl process in order to allow it to provide the input stream and read the output stream and the error stream. This is the overwhelmingly most common case. However, in your case you want to have these directed to the current input/output streams so the user can see them. That's not too difficult, but requires a little more code:

```
# You need to use [file nativename] with cmd
# The double quotes are for highlighting purposes here on Stack Overflow only
exec cmd /c [file nativename "D:/test/run.bat"] <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

The critical bit (if my diagnosis is correct) is the `<@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr` which joins up the channels.

It's also possible that it is `file nativename` that is actually doing the important thing. Filenames passed to non-Tcl processes on Windows usually need to be presented in native form (mainly, with `\` instead of `/`). And you don't need to put `\` in front of `/`.

Comment: get this error message with your example: Error (245021): Failed to run Tcl script D:/test/run.tcl. Error: channel "stdin" wasn't opened for reading.

Comment: Ah, that's an indication that things are Broke As Hell in the execution environment. Best advice then is to change that batch script so that it never reads data interactively from the user, as that is unlikely to ever work when you run it in that location.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will change the batch file in order to have no user input